# Special character not encoded in [Required (ErrorMessage = "Latitude must be between -180&deg; and 180&deg;)]

Tags: data-annotations

When the validation message is given on the webpage though, it doesn't show the proper degree symbol and shows it without encoding it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that adding special characters to the cshtml may be the best way and the following will show the correct degree symbol in the validation message.

```
<span asp-validation-for="User" class="text-danger">Error Message with &deg;</span>
```